# Check if a value has data or not in SRSS

Tags: ssrs-2012

I am developing an SRSS report and I want to check if a field has value or not.
If it has, I want to assign it with a "Yes", if not a "No".
So far, I did this below:
=IIF(Fields!id.Value,"Yes","No")

Thanks and appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

IIF first argument is boolean condition and Fields!id.Value is not a boolean to make it work you need to call IsNothing method to evaluate field value and return true in case of null. the expression code needs to be as below

=IIF(IsNothing(Fields!id.Value),"No","Yes")

Comment: @supersnell is answered your question?